How to get the values in a Python list when their indices are mixed at the start and end
I was trying to perform a simple moving average of a list with the particularity that the end of the list it's the start of itself, but when, for example, with a list  from 1 to 9 using 3 samples I try to:
original_list = [*range(1,10)]

print(sum(original_list[-1:2])/3) 

The ouput is 0.0 and should be (9+1+2)/3 = 4.
My first guess was that I wasnt chosing the right values from the indices, so I printed them individually:
print(original_list[-1:], original_list[:2])

# Print:
# [9] [1, 2]

Which was as expected, so I what's wrong in my previous print? How should I do it?
What I tried is to do both separed and join them so:
print(sum(original_list[-1:] + original_list[:2]) / 3)

# Print:
# 4

That is the right value, however if I increase the samples to 5 for example and I try:
import math
original_list = [*range(1,10)]

def MA(index):
    to_be_averaged = original_list[-2 + index:] + original_list[:3 + index]
    print(to_be_averaged)
    print(sum(to_be_averaged) / len(to_be_averaged))

MA(0)
# Print
# [8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
# 4.6

MA(1)
# Print
# [9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# 3.8

MA(2)
# Print
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# 4.285714285714286

What a mess at index 2, what's going on? How should I do it? I feel like it should be a simple way to get a range from a to b independently if the indices are positive or negative.

original_list[-1:2] is empty.  Slices don't go backwards unless you explicitly use a negative step.

iirc there's a cycle function somewhere in collections

I saw that! then how you would do it if you input a index of the original list and a sample size?

"I feel like it should be a simple way to get a range from a to b independently if the indices are positive or negative." Keep in mind that lists are linear. Therefore sometimes (if the second index is smaller than the first) you'll need to concatenate two sublists instead of using only one.

Do you care about speed? If yes, then how large are you lists and samples?

Thanks for the answers and comments, it really helped me to undertand the issue!
However, none of the addressed to the main question of how to do the moving average as it was presented. I ended up doing little tricks and a change of how to create the new list to be averaged (instead of slicing, list comprehension).
import math
import numpy as np

def MA(index, sample):
    N = len(original_list)
    neighbors = math.floor(sample/2)
    desired_range = (np.array(range(sample)) - neighbors + index) % N
    
    to_be_averaged = [original_list[i] for i in desired_range]
    print(to_be_averaged)
    return sum(to_be_averaged)/sample

I try to explain line by line:
N = len(original_list)

Gets the total lenght of the original list. In this case could be done only once but in my application I might use this function for different lists so I also input the list and this variable N changes.
neighbors = math.floor(sample/2)

This allows me to know how many up and down samples I'll be taking, remember that for this type of calculations tend to use odd numbers so your index is in the center. math.floor just rounds to the lowest integral if nothing else is passed.
desired_range = (np.array(range(sample)) - neighbors + index) % N

There is the funny part, here I try to get the range that I want but in indices to be used after. I create an np.array so I can perform addition and substraction operations to a list, which I create using range, the size of the range is the sample that I want and I adjust it to be previous and after samples just slicing it by substracting the neighbors, then I add the desired index so like that I have the indeces of the positions of interest, however it can happend that we add too much and get out of range of the list, that's why using the mod % N wraps around the list size and anything above N starts from the beginning of the list.
The rest is basically a list comprehension along to the desired range which we already created and suming and dividing by the sample size.
Hope it helps!
original_list = [*range(5)]

# Tests

[print(MA(i,3)) for i in range((len(original_list)))]
# [4, 0, 1]
# 1.6666666666666667
# [0, 1, 2]
# 1.0
# [1, 2, 3]
# 2.0
# [2, 3, 4]
# 3.0
# [3, 4, 0]
# 2.3333333333333335
[print(MA(i,5)) for i in range((len(original_list)))]
# [3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
# 2.0
# [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
# 2.0
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# 2.0
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
# 2.0
# [2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
# 2.0


That's ... not how slicing works. There are couple of misconceptions here, so we should sort them out one by one.
First of all, when you start with a negative index on a slice, we work from the end of the list. So l[-1:] -> [9] is only ever going to produce a single value unless you also use a negative step. If you do use a negative step, you'll get more values, but it won't wrap around like you want, it'll work backward: l[-1:2:-1] -> [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4].
So that's our first problem. Next, you have to remember that list slices are half intervals ([)) - they include the start index, but not the end index. So even if it did wrap around, l[-1:2] wouldn't include 2, it would stop at 1.
With all that said, you might be best served by a deque to rotate the list into the state you want so you can easily slice, and then restore it.  Ex:
from collections import deque

d = deque(range(1,10))

def rolling(d, start, end):
  if start < 0:
    d.rotate(-start)
  print(sum(list(d)[0:end+1])/len(list(d)[0:end+1]))
  if start < 0:
    d.rotate(start)

rolling(d, -1, 2) # 4

print(d) # deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])


A slice is a block of a list basically, it can skip values but doesn't wrap around the edges. With your list[-1:2], you're telling to return all values that are both past the 9th index and before the 2nd, which is obviously none of them.
The full list is the same as list[:n1] + list[n1:-n2] + list[-n2:], and what you're needing is the first and last slice, so you're correct in that you have to do list[:n] and list[-n:] separately.
As to why your MA function is inputting weird behaviour for index=1, it's simply because you're using original_list[-2 + index:] instead of original_list[-2 - index:]. When you gave the input as 2, the slice was returning the entire list, hence why you got way more values than expected.
With that fixed:
def MA(index):
    to_be_averaged = original_list[-2 - index:] + original_list[:3 + index]
    print(to_be_averaged)
    print(sum(to_be_averaged) / len(to_be_averaged))

>>> MA(0)
[8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
4.6

>>> MA(1)
[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4.857142857142857

>>> MA(2)
[6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5.0


itertools.cycle doesn't work like i thought, so i've come up with this:
def cycle(arr, start, size):
    print(f'start: {start}, size: {size}')
    start = start % len(arr)
    end = start+size
    cycles = end // len(arr)
    arr=arr*(1+cycles)
    res = arr[start:end]
    print(res)
    print('average:', sum(res)/len(res))
    print()

works with really out of range indices and samples
start: -15, size: 32
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
average: 5.15625

start: -11, size: 5
[8, 9, 1, 2, 3]
average: 4.6

start: -1, size: 3
[9, 1, 2]
average: 4.0

start: 0, size: 9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
average: 5.0

start: 0, size: 18
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
average: 5.0

start: 58, size: 3
[5, 6, 7]
average: 6.0


How did you think itertools.cycle works?
